# checking a part of a String > 1

Tags: regex, bash

I want to check a string using a bash script.

I have a series of archives created with suffixes such as "part1.rar", "part2.rar" or simply some number indicating the position as in "test99.rar". I want to take some action based on a check that the current part is not the first one.

For example, "test99.rar", "747547548.part2.rar" and "archivexyz.part123.rar" should trigger the action but "hello1.rar" and "multiarchive.part1.rar" should not.

I tried this unsuccessfully:

```
if [[ "$archive" = *.part[>1].rar ]]
then
    echo "test - greater as 1"
fi
```

The following code is working but with a single digit only at a time:

```
if [[ "$archive" = *.part2.rar ]]
then
    echo "test - greater as 1"
fi
```

Can you help me please to find a solution?

Comment: So, do you want to take an action in case of test99.rar since it doesn't contain the "part" string?

Comment: right, test99.rar should do an action.

Comment: cool, see my answer below. don't forget to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
if [[ $archive =~ ([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]+).rar$ ]]
then
    echo "test - greater as 1"
fi
```

Please note the `=~` operator which is what you should use when matching strings against a regex in bash. See [this article](http://www.itworld.com/operating-systems/355273/unix-bashs-regular-expressions) for more details on what is possible with regex on bash.

Comment: Well, that is a dangerous thing to say :) I wish you'd take time to understand it and reuse the knowledge gained. Charms won't take us too far!

Comment: I read your linked article and I had understood the =~ operator. It's really great to check single characters.

Comment: Nope, it's way more powerful than that. Play around with it a little.

Answer (score 0):

A real oneliner:

```
sed 's/.*[^0-9]1.rar//;t;s/.*/test - greater than 1/' $archive
```